# Создание динамического двумерного массива (С#)

Tags: c#, массивы, динамические-массивы

Необходимо создать двумерный динамический массив и заполнить его с клавиатуры.
В поисках нужного решения, нашел информацию о том, что в С# роль динамического массива на себя "берёт" List и к нему был приведен следующий фрагмент кода:

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();
```

Не совсем понятно как с этим работать..
Желательно пояснить как справляться с заданием и сделать отсылку на книгу/видеоматериал для лучшего понимания темы.
Спасибо!

Comment: А чего тут не понятного? `List<List<int>>` - это тип `List`, который в себе содержит тип `List`, который в себе содержит тип `int`. Ну и создавайте эти типы, `lists.Add(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 });` или `var list = new List<int>(); list.Add(1); list.Add(2); lists.Add(list);`. Ведь просто, не? Сами пробовали решить то задачку? Любая документация по коллекция покажит все необходимое.

Comment: `роль динамического массива` на себя берёт всё-таки динамический массив

Comment: Похоже на [XY-проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567), для чего вам это?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ данная конструкция - не двумерный массив, потому что в ней каждая строка может быть произвольного размера. Здесь сокрее нужен вменяемый враппер над всем этим, но это уже зависит от поставленной бизнес-задачи.

Comment: @aepot Ну вопрос "`List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();` как с этим работать.". Я не думаю, что здесь автору принципиально массив или коллекция, в любом случае, на поставленный вопрос ответ даст любая документация, ибо как по мне, спрашивать у SO как работать с `List<>`, ну такое себе...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работает это просто

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();
```

можно представить так если представить

```
class IntList: List<int> {

}

List<IntList> lists = new List<IntList>();
```

список объектов `IntList`.

т.е чтоб добавить в него элемент нежно его создать экземпяр класса `IntList`

```
IntList item = new IntList(); //у нас это List<int> item = new List<int>();
```

а item в свою очередь это список Int
элементы которые добавляются через

```
item.add(10)
```

а сам `item` добавляется через

```
lists.add(item)
```